# Sitecore Redirect to Original Page After Login or SSO Authentication

Tags: login, sitecore-login

I'm working with Sitecore 10 and facing an issue with user redirection post-login and SSO authentication. I have implemented a custom HttpRequestProcessor to check if the user is authenticated and redirect them to the login page if not. The code snippet is as follows:

```
public class ValidateUserSession : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        // ... existing code ...
        if (!Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn && Sitecore.Context.Item["Is Authentication Required"] == "1")
        {
            string returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string loginPageUrl = $"/sitecore/login?returnUrl={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)}";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginPageUrl, false);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        // ... existing code ...
    }
}
```

This code successfully redirects unauthenticated users to the login page. However, after successful login or SSO authentication, users are not redirected back to the original page they came from but to the Sitecore shell. I want them to return to the page where the redirect initially happened, regardless of whether they use standard login or SSO.

How can I modify this code to ensure users are redirected back to their original page after logging in or completing SSO authentication?